# Create new rows if transpose index has duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have 2 columns :

```
Col1    Col2
------------
Date1    A
Date1    B
Date2    C
Date3    A
```

output should be :

Columns : A,B,C

```
A        B         C
------------------------
Date1   Date1      Date2
Date3   NaN        Nan
```

And also my column list is A,B,C,D,E,F

if my final results doesn't have other columns like D,E,F . I need to create missing values for those columns

Final output:

```
A        B         C        D       E        F
----------------------------------------------
Date1   Date1      Date2    NaN    NaN      NaN
Date3   NaN        NaN      NaN    NaN      Nan
```

I have tried Transpose

`df.set_index("Col2").T` but its giving A B C A as column names ,in which case I need second A's column value should be appended to first A column

Answer (score 2):

#### [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

You can use a helper series to create an index, then pivot and reindex columns:

```
res = df.assign(index=df.groupby('Col2').cumcount())\
        .pivot(index='index', columns='Col2')\
        .xs('Col1', axis=1).reindex(columns=tuple('ABCDEF'))

print(res)

Col2       A      B      C   D   E   F
index                                 
0      Date1  Date1  Date2 NaN NaN NaN
1      Date3    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crosstab` and `reindex`:

```
categories = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

c = df.groupby('Col2').cumcount()
pd.crosstab(c, df.Col2, df.Col1, aggfunc='first').reindex(categories, axis=1)

Col2       A      B      C   D   E   F
row_0                                 
0      Date1  Date1  Date2 NaN NaN NaN
1      Date3    NaN    NaN NaN NaN NaN
```